# Ansible: How to pass tags between playbooks

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I'm Having 2 Ansible playbooks named below, I'm trying to call **main.yml** from **Azure-Pipeline.yml** while calling **main.yml** how can I pass tags from **Azure-Pipelin.yml** to **main.yml**

```
- Azure-Pipeline.yml
- main.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to Ansible's `tags` documentation:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#adding-tags-to-imports

You should be able to add a tags block to your import or include:

```yaml
- name: Import tasks from foo.yml
  import_tasks: foo.yml
  tags: [ web, foo ]
```